# Importing Negative Values in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-import

I am using SQL Servr 2012 and attempting to import values from a `.txt` file using SSIS. One column in my `.txt` file is exclusively negative numbers and these all show up as null after I perform the import.

These negative numbers are formatted so that the negative sign is at the end of the number, like this:

```
0000030.90-
```

I would like this number to display as -30.90 once imported. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think I found in the past that if I import those as DT_DECIMAL, it just worked. Maybe it's locale-dependent?

Answer (score 2):

Use a derived column transformation with an expression to move the negative sign to the front, and output it as a decimal datatype.

Comment: Yep.  You'll have to force the import column type to String or Unicode String, using Advanced editor.  SSIS will probably "helpfully" decide that this column is numeric.

Comment: You can also use SQL server Import and Export Wizard (Database->Task->import data-> )